# Printing columns from a TSV in reverse based on user input date ranges

Tags: c++, csv

Hello I have a TSV in the following format

```
Date             EastStorage    EastElevation    WestStorage    WestElevation
01/01/2018          59.94           574             32.67           574.33 
01/02/2018          59.89           573.99          32.57           574.29
01/03/2018          59.89           573.97          32.44           574.24
01/04/2018          59.9            573.97          32.22           574.07
```

It goes on until 12/31/2018.
Now I must output date ranges and WestElevation values in reverse order based on user input so on execution:

```
$ ./reverse-order
Enter earlier date: 05/29/2018
Enter later date: 06/02/2018

06/02/2018  590.22 ft
06/01/2018  590.23 ft
05/31/2018  590.24 ft
05/30/2018  590.26 ft
05/29/2018  590.32 ft
```

The following code outputs 12/31/18's corresponding WestElevation value over and over again.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string date;
    string dates[365];
    string begindate;
    string enddate;
    bool isworking = false;
    double eastSt, eastEl, westSt, westEl;
    double elevation[365];
    for (int j = 0; j < 365; j++) {
        dates[j] = "empty";
    }
    cout << "Enter the earlier date: " << endl;
    cin >> begindate;
    cout << "Enter the later date: " << endl;
    cin >> enddate;
    ifstream fin("Current_Reservoir_Levels.tsv");
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cerr << "File cannot be opened for reading." << endl;
        exit(1); // exit if failed to open the file
    }
    string junk; // new string variable
    getline(fin, junk); // read one line from the file
    while (fin >> date >> eastSt >> eastEl >> westSt >> westEl) {
        // this loop reads the file line-by-line
        // extracting 5 values on each iteration
        fin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); //skips to the end of line,
        //ignorring the remaining columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
            if (begindate == date) {
                isworking = true;
                if (begindate == enddate) {
                    dates[i] = date;
                    elevation[i] = westEl;

                    isworking = false;
                }
            }
            else if (enddate == date) {
                dates[i] = date;
                elevation[i] = westEl;
                isworking = true;
            }
            if (isworking == true) {
                dates[i] = date;
                elevation[i] = westEl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int a = 365; a >= 0; a--) {
        if (dates[a] != "emtpy" && elevation[a] != 0) {
            cout << dates[a] << " " << elevation[a] << endl;
        }
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I think using arrays to complete this task is probably the simplest way. But I think my logic in handling the input dates is a bit off for this specific case. How can I fix my code to achieve the desired output?

Solution:

```
while(fin >> date >> eastSt >> eastEl >> westSt >> westEl) {

    if(begindate==date)
    {
     inrange=true;
    }
    if(enddate==date)
    {
     elevation[i]=westEl;
     dates[i]=date;
     i++;
     inrange=false;
    }

    if(inrange==true)
    {
     elevation[i]=westEl;
     dates[i]=date;
     i++;
    }
fin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

}
for(int a=i-1; a>=0; a--)
{
  {
    cout<< dates[a]<<" "<< elevation[a]<<endl;
  }

}
fin.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping throuch your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a student just learning C++ have not learned to use the debugger yet :(

Comment: Time to start learning it. That's a pretty essential skill doing any kind of software development. If you use an IDE, it should be a piece of cake for any beginner to grasp debugging doable in 2 - 3 days at least for the most frequent used things like stepping, watching variables, breakpoints etc.

Comment: I'll get on that immediately. This is actually for my software development class but debugging is not until later in the semester

Comment: Sounds like your teacher is incompetent. They should have covered that together with the 1st _Hello World!_ program teaching you.

Comment: feelsbadman.jpeg

Comment: I once had an instructor state, "If you write your programs correctly you don't have to debug." 100% accurate, but still useless. Don't wait on the instructor or the lessons. The amount of time you invest now in learning the basics of debuggers will pay itself off in saved time before the instructor gets around to covering it. [This covers the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017), but they are all very similar in basic capabilities these days.

Comment: @JohnReal Will Input data be sorted according to date?